# Can we perform the Code Analysis using FxCopCmd for a directory(Collection of .exe and .dll) instead of for a particular file(.exe or .dll)

Tags: c#, dll, fxcop, fxcopcmd

I am facing a problem with analyzing the code using FxCopCmd. It works perfectly when i check for a sing file but it doesn't work when I replace it with a directory. May be i am not using the correct Command.

```
fxcopcmd.exe /file:"C:\Users\ConsoleApplication18.exe" /out:"C:\Users\212553210\Documents\srifxcop.xml"
```

The above command works perfectly. but instead of a file, I mention a directory like

```
fxcopcmd.exe /file:"C:\Users" /out:"C:\Users\212553210\Documents\srifxcop.xml"
```

Now it gives an error saying "Analysis was not performed". If any body can help me out in this issue will be very thankful.

Comment: There's an example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429449(v=vs.80).aspx) using `*.*` as a wildcard for assemblies - does that work? Or are you trying to do a whole subtree recursively? Are you sure it supports that?

Comment: I added slash even at the end too. but its not working

Comment: @Rup that is not working...

Comment: A different approach:
Create a batch file which will read the folder and get all the file names.
loop them and call FxCop each iteration.